# Connect push button to ArduiMU

Tags: communication, button

I've got an ArduiMU V3+ and would like to connect an ordinary push button to it.
How would I connect it to it.

[image]

Comment: Presumably connect it between ground and an unused input, then activate a pullup resistor on the input.  This really depends on the **software** you are running, and on any **unique requirements** of your application (such as acceptability of various types of failure).

Comment: May I use analog-inputs as well?

Comment: This site realy exists as a fallback for things which are not covered in or not clear in the documentation, not as an alterantive to it.  Please start with http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins